# Giving map markers a unique ID then accessing outside of the canvas

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have created an array of markers on a map. And I have a list of these markers outside of the canvas. I would like to learn about and create some interaction between these.

My markers are created like so:

```
var markers = [];
var marker = [];
var i;  

// var places is an array of locations
for (var i=0;i<places.length;i++) {

        var place = places[i];
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]);

         marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]),map: map
        });

        marker[i].set('id','marker_'+i);

        markers.push(marker[i]);

}
```

I thought perhaps by using [MVCObject](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCObject) I could set the id of the marker, and perhaps my marker would have an id of 'marker_1' for example, which I could access in the DOM with jquery via something like:

```
$('#marker_0').doSomething();
```

But this doesn't seem to be the case.

How can I give each marker a unique Id to access in the DOM outside the map canvas and API?

Comment: `marker[i].doSomething()` should work with your sample-code

Comment: @Dr.Molle That sounds logical, but if I pull up the console after everything is loaded and do something like marker[0].remove() it will tell me that marker isn't defined.

Comment: currently you didn't define the arrays `marker` or  `markers` inside your code. When you define it somewhere  be sure that  it's globally accessible.

Comment: My apologies, but in my code I do define the arrays (I think) - i've updated the code above to reflect that.

Comment: remove the `var`-keywords to make the variables global accessible.

Comment: I had no idea that made it global! now when I try it, that works... but when I add my function onto it jquery style, e.g. .remove() it says 'object has no method remove'.

Comment: markers are not DOM-nodes, you may modify them by using the methods of the MAPS-API, e.g. `marker[0].setMap(null) `

Comment: I see, I think. So if I want an object outside of the map_canvas to interact with a marker I have to do it within the maps api.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question, [this answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436165/google-maps-adddomlistener-on-div-added-by-jquery-only-sees-last-iteration-of-lo).

I created a function var inside my initialize function of the google map:

```
var markers = [];
var marker = [];
var i;  

// var places is an array of locations
for (var i=0;i<places.length;i++) {

    var place = places[i];
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]);

     marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]),map: map
    });

    marker[i].set('id','marker_'+i);

    markers.push(marker[i]);


    var mouseoverListener = (function(i) {
        return function() {

            alert[i];

        };
    })(i);

}
```

And then initiated the [addDomListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#DomEvents) like so:

```
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('place'+i+''), 'mouseover', mouseoverListener);
```

When I hovered over my list item, it alerted the index of the marker it was supposed to, so instead of alert[i] I could access control over each of the markers.